# esse algoritmo é para verificar divisor

Tags: c, c++

esse algoritmo é para verificar se o primeiro é divisor do segundo e no final apresentar se é divisor ou não divisor, não apresenta erro, mas não sei como continuar

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int n1,n2,resto,res;

printf ("\nDigite um numero:");
scanf ("%d", &n1);

printf ("\nDigite um numero:");
scanf ("%d", &n2);

res = n1 / n2;
resto= n1%n2;

printf("\nResultado da divisao de %d / %d = %d. \n",n1,n2,res);

getch();
return(0);
}

Comment: Olá Eleny, acredito que a forma como você fez a pergunta não se enquadra nos protocolos de perguntas do SOpt. Dê uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, talvez ajude. e dessa forma facilite a resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: Acrescente `if (n1 % n2 == 0)
 printf(%d é divisor de %d\n", n2, n1);
else
 printf(%d não é divisor de %d\n", n2, n1);
`

Comment: Atenção apenas ao que você postou: `verificar se o primeiro é divisor do segundo`, neste caso inverta `n1` e `n2` pois a resposta acima  verifica se `n2` é ou não divisor de `n1`.

Answer (score 1):

Se A divide B, o resto da divisão de A por B é zero, ou seja `a%b == 0`.

Apenas faça:

```
if(resto == 0)
   printf("\n%d é divisor de %d!",n1,n2);
else
   printf("\n%d não é divisor de %d!",n1,n2)
```